# What is the あと in 努めてあとを濁さないように

Tags: word-usage

水面から飛び立つ鳥は努めてあとを濁さないように。
Sentence from jisho for 努めて.
Can anyone help clarify what the あと here means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This あと is 後 (or 跡) in kanji. It has several meanings, but in this case it vaguely refers to "something left behind" or "the situation of a place after you left it". More concretely, あと in this sentence refers to a swamp where migrating birds have been staying. Note that this example sentence is taken from [this well-known idiom](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4%E9%B3%A5%E8%B7%A1%E3%82%92%E6%BF%81%E3%81%95%E3%81%9A).

Other examples:

> - 私は今月でこの会社を辞めるので、**後**のことはあなたに任せます。
> - [後は野となれ山となれ](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%AF%E9%87%8E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8C%E5%B1%B1%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8C) (idiom)